# Plotting multiple overlapping histograms with columns from two separate pandas data frames

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization, data-science

I've got two pandas data frames with the same column names ('Height', 'Weight', 'Alc'), but one is with dirty data and one with cleaned data.

To visualise my cleaning, I want to make a histogram with **overlapping** bars showing the dirty data and the cleaned data for a given variable on the same chart. Eg for 'Height' I want a chart looking like the one pictured below, with dirty 'Height' data in one colour, and cleaned 'Height' data in another.

Importantly, I want to make such a chart for **all** of my variables (ie 'Height', 'Weight', and 'Alc').

In order to achieve this I've tried appending the data frames and plotting the histograms from a single data frame. Unfortunately it produces just regular histograms, not overlapping ones.

Thanks for any help!

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# DIRTY DATA FRAME  
data = [[1.0, 10, 0], [0.0, 12, 0.4], [2.0, 918, 0.9], [2.0, 918, 0.9]]   
df_dirty = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Height', 'Weight', 'Alc']) 


# CLEAN DATA FRAME
data2 = [[1.0, 10, np.nan], [0.0, 12, 0.4], [np.nan, np.nan, 0.9], [np.nan, np.nan, 0.9]]   
df_clean = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns = ['Height', 'Weight', 'Alc']) 


# ADDITION OF GROUP-BY VARIABLE   
my_dfs = [df_dirty, df_clean]
my_status = ['dirty','clean']
for dataframe, status in zip(my_dfs, my_status):
    dataframe['groupbyvar'] = status


# DATA FRAME FOR PLOTTING  
df_plotting = df_dirty.append(df_clean, ignore_index=True)


# HISTOGRAMS FOR ALL COLUMNS IN DATA FRAME FOR PLOTTING   
for col in df_plotting:
    df_plotting.hist(by="groupbyvar", column=col)
```

**EDIT**:
The above chart is just a picture to explain what I want, my current code does **NOT** make it.

Comment: that looks pretty overlapping to me.

Comment: @Quang Hoang. Hi! The above chart is just a picture to explain what I want, my current code does not make it. Thanks!